# Showing more than two name & space issue

Tags: php

I am making an PM system for my users.

In the recipient field you type in a full name. When you submit i want to make sure it's the right user he sends to.

So if he type "Megan Fox", it's a full match of a user. But if he type Meg F or Megan, Fox it will return "Did you mean Megan Fox?"

So...

Now I have thought what if there's more than one with the name "Megan" or the lastname "Fox". I made a while() for that, and it will return if theres more than 1, "Who did you mean: Matt Fox, Megan Fox?"

Now I havnt found where It goes wrong, I got 3 rows with the lastname "Fox", it only shows two of them in the "Who did you mean?"

How can I solve this?

And if I only enter a space in the recipient field, it will return all users, in the table. How can i prevent this?

Here's what my code looks like:

```
$mot = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mottagare']);
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $mot, 2));
$qur = mysql_query("
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname = '$lastname') AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') 
 OR (firstname LIKE '$firstname%' AND lastname LIKE '$lastname%')
 OR firstname LIKE '$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '$firstname%'
 ORDER BY (firstname = '$firstname' AND lastname='$lastname') DESC");

 $get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);

 if(mysql_num_rows($qur) == 1){
    if($get["full"] == 1){
    echo $get["id"];
    }else{
     echo "Did you mean ".$get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"]." ?";
    }
 }elseif(mysql_num_rows($qur) > 1){
    while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur)) {
       $name[] = $get["firstname"]." ".$get["lastname"];
   }

   if(count($name) > 1) {
       echo 'Who did you mean?<br>';
   } else {
       echo 'Did you mean: ';
   }
   echo implode('<br>', $name);

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
$get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);
```

you already fetched the first of your names without appending it to the $name array, so in this line:

```
while($get = mysql_fetch_array($qur)) {
```

the first one will not be fetched from the DB again.

Comment: But.. the lines are in different if´s.. The while work, that's not the problem

Comment: No, the first one is in no "if" at all, it is always executed.

Comment: @Johnson : if the while worked, you wouldn't be here asking us why it doesn't. Your first mysql_fetch_array is always executed and removes the first element from the result set, which is why it never even reaches the while.

Comment: Ohh sorry, the first fetch_array, i forgot to move it inside the if ==1, it works perfect now thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

For your space problem, you can require that a certain number of non-space characters must be entered before results are suggested.

If there are only a few users, you can also try to make suggestions based on [Levenshtein distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) to correct for spelling mistakes.

Comment: Oh, yes, I overlooked the space problem. Victor is right, just don't execute the whole thing if trim($_POST['mottagare'])=="".